# How can I deserialise a JSON result where its Root is a unique ID into an Object class

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, deserialization

I am currently trying to learn to work with API systems using C# .net core 3 and Newtonsoft.

The following call to Steam API is what I am using
for specific game details. For example http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=72850

This returns JSON similar to this ( I have cut it down for simplicity )

```
{
    "72850": {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "type": "game",
            "name": "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",
            "steam_appid": 72850,
            "required_age": 0,
            "is_free": false
        }
    }
}
```

Each return has the unique ID as the root in this case 72850 and I am at a loss on how to map this into an object class so I can process this data. The "data" element is what I am really interested in but as a beginner, I am at a loss.

Comment: A `Dictionary<long, ClassObject>` is a simple method. The `ClassObject` has two properties: `success: bool` and `data : Class`. Build these two (or whatever other class objects you have there) classes as usual. Then you can deserialize as `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, ClassObject>>(json);`

Comment: Or `List<Dictionary<long, ClassObject>>`, if you have more JSON objects indexed like that.

Comment: @Jimi this works perfectly and I would accept this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This API indexes its response using the internal Identifier of the Item requested.
This is a common scenario and it's also a quite efficient method to organize objects based on an Indexer, which can then be used to store or retrieve these objects, from a database, for example.

A common way to deserialize JSON object indexed like this, is to use a Dictionary, where the Key is Indexer and the Value the `RootObject` of the class structure (the Model) that further describes the JSON properties.

Some notes on the current JSON:

- The API looks like it's built to represent the JSON on a HTML document, since the internal strings are formatted ready for presentation on a HTML page. This can be less useful when used elsewhere and can also create a problem when deserializing.
  I've added a trivial clean-up, replacing what can cause a problem for sure:

  ```
  json = json.Replace(@"\/", "/").Replace(@"\t", "");
  ```
- I've added some more properties and classes to those presented in the question: it may be useful to see when a JsonProperty attribute is needed and when is it's not. For example: the `[JsonProperty("type")]` attribute is added to the `public string GameType { get; set; }` property, since `Type` is a keyword that may be misinterpreted, as is `Name` etc.
- `Json.Net` is not case sensitive, so the JSON property `background` can be assigned to a .Net property `public Uri Background { get; set; }` without problem.

A couple of WebSites that provide a free service to format, validate and convert JSON object to a class model:

- [JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) - Formatting, validation
- [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) - Multi-language Class Model generator

---

Download the JSON using the WebClient.DownloadString() method, clean up the JSON and deserialize:

```
var steamUri = new Uri("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=72850")
string json = new WebClient(steamUri).DownloadString();
json = json.Replace(@"\/", "/").Replace(@"\t", "");

var steamObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, SteamApps.SteamAppDetails>>(json);
```

---

**Class structure**:

```
public class SteamApps
{
    public class SteamAppDetails
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string GameType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string GameName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("steam_appid")]
        public long SteamAppid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("required_age")]
        public long RequiredAge { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_free")]
        public bool IsFree { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("short_description")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("supported_languages")]
        public string Languages { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("header_image")]
        public string HeaderImage { get; set; }

        public string WebSite { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price_overview")]
        public PriceOverview PriceOverview { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, bool> Platforms { get; set; }
        public List<Screenshot> Screenshots { get; set; }
        public Uri Background { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

    public class PriceOverview
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public long Initial { get; set; }
        public long Final { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discount_percent")]
        public decimal DiscountPercent { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("initial_formatted")]
        public string InitialFormatted { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("final_formatted")]
        public string FinalFormatted { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Screenshot
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("path_thumbnail")]
        public string PathThumbnail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("path_full")]
        public string PathFull { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Category
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you only need the "Data" element from the json, it is fairly simple using Newtonsoft. First make a class with all the fields that the Data element contains as shown below:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Steam_AppId { get; set; }
    public int Required_Age { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Free { get; set; }
}
```

Now in order to map the json response, which I'm assuming is stored in a string at the moment, you have to Deserialize it to map to your C# class. And you can do that very easily:

**Edit: A more elegant solution which avoids all the string manipulation nuisance**

```
//You already have this but I created it in order to test
string jsonResult = "{ \"72850\": " +
    "{ \"success\": true, \"data\": " +
        "{ \"type\": \"game\", \"name\": \"The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim\", " +
            "\"steam_appid\": 72850, \"required_age\": 0, \"is_free\": false } }";

//JObject is a class in Newtonsoft library for handling json objects
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);

//Since you're sending a request to the api, either you already have the id 
//"72850" or can extract it easily from uri. This line gets data's value
//by 1st searching for key = "72850" and then within that a key = "data"
JToken dataToken = jObject["72850"]["data"];

Data data = dataToken.ToObject<Data>();
```

Reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

**Older solution**

```
//getting the value portion of data element/key
string jsonData = "{" + jsonResult.Substring(jsonResult.IndexOf("\"type"));
//removing the extra } from the end
jsonData = jsonData.TrimEnd('}');

//map the json string to a C# object
var dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonData);
```

So now you'll see the json values mapped to your Data object which in this case is dataObj. Feel free to ask questions if anything's not clear. Cheers!